# Compiling a .CPP using GCC

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, compilation

how do I compile a .c or .cpp file using GCC?
I need to include some standard libraries (fstream, string, iostream) - how do I do this?

For clarification, here:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include"ocgenerator.h";
#include"structures.h";
#include"util.h";
#include"util2.h";
using namespace std;
```

(my .h files are in the same directory as the src file) 
If I use the command:
gcc src.cpp -o src.o

I get a lot of errors: memcpy, atoi, atol, strncmp, etc, ... "are not declared in this scope". What should I add to the command?

edit: Or is it a scope thing, and do I have to add std:: to all those functions?

Comment: `#include <cstring>`, `#include <cstdlib>`.

Answer (score 1):

`memcpy` and `strncmp` are declared in `<cstring>`, `atoi` and `atol` in `<cstdlib>`. Just include these headers to bring in their declarations.

Side notes :

- No semicolon after preprocessor directives, including `#include ""`.
- No `using namespace std;`, **especially** not in headers !
  ([Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice))
- Since you're building a C++ project, don't forget to link with the standard library via `-lstdc++`, or use `g++` which forwards it to the linker for you.

Note that with GCC you don't have to prefix standard C functions with `std::` (as they are also declared in the global namespace), but you should anyway for your code to be standard-compliant.

Answer (score 0):

The cplusplus site helps out. If you search for a specific function, on the top you will find the necessary references for the code to compile:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atol/

You can even check in the URL. In this case, you need 'cstdlib'.

Regarding the compiler, there are several available, g++ is a good option.

I also suggest creating a makefile for automating the building process, because it becomes an headache when your codebase grows.

Answer (score 0):

For *any* library function you use in your code, read the man page for that function to see which header declares it, and `#include` that header in any source file that uses the function.

For example, `man memcpy` shows the `memcpy(3)` man page (the `(3)` refers to section 3 of the manual; use `man 3 memcpy` to specify the section).

> **NAME**
>     memcpy - copy memory area
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>   **`#include <string.h>`**
>
> **`void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);`**
>   ...

`memcpy` is part of the C standard library, and is declared in `<string.h>`. For C++ you can use `<string.h>`, but it's probably better to use `<cstring>`, which puts the function name in the `std` namespace. In general, each standard C header `<foo.h>` is duplicated as a C++ header `<cfoo>`.

> I get a lot of errors: `memcpy`, `atoi`, `atol`, `strncmp`, etc,

`memcpy` and `strncmp` are declared in `<cstring>`. `atoi` and `atol` are `<cstdlib>` (or in `<string.h>` and `<stdlib.h>` if you're programming in C rather than in C++).

And be sure to use the `g++` command, not the `gcc` command, to compile C++ source. They both invoke the same compiler (`gcc` compiles C++ code if the source file name ends in `.cpp`), but the `g++` command adds some options that are needed for C++.